# I know html/css want to dive in to web development, which one to start with?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django

I want to dive in to web development, I briefly looked into RoR, Django and PHP but not sure which want to start with.

I want to start with something that is the easiest to learn for someone with zero programming knowledge. I know this could be subjective, but I will go with the one with the most convincing answer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since it's clearly subjective as you state, it's OT for SO. I think PHP is an abomination from a language standpoint, but that's a flame war for another day.

Comment: Everyone started at `the bottom of the ladder` and there is no `easy way`. I paid my dues as others have, and still am learning. Heck, even the `pros` keep on learning. Touch different ones and see which one feels right `for you`. Enjoy the adventure!

Comment: I would recommend learning a cms like wordpress or something - gives you an idea of how web works, and eventually start off with some framework like php

Comment: @DaveNewton you must be a java fan boy.

Comment: @Orangepill That makes zero sense. Java is pretty much an abomination too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strongly depends by what you want to do.
First if you need learning a programming language to become an employee of another company then you should take precise choices. In fact some programming languages are better paid and have better salaries.
Instead if you want to learn to work as a freelancer or just for fun, then you are free to chose whatever you like the most.

Based on my own experience, I am a PHP, Javascript/jQuery developer with over 5 years of experience. I worked as a freelancer for a lot of time and honestly I earned good money.

Now I am working as an employee for another company and the salary is not that good.

Salaries are much higher at the moment for iOS developer and Java developers.

So if you want to start learning to work for other companies go for C, then Objective-C and lastly Java.

If you want to learn for becoming a freelancer or just for fun I strongly advise you to start with PHP Procedural and then Object Oriented.

With PHP you can really do SO many things and it is a so powerful language.

Also many of the most known CMSs are built with PHP and there is a LOT of documentation to help you studying.

Also by learning PHP first ( very well ) you should be able to start learning more complex languages such Java with less pain.

In any case just chose what you feel is the best for you and based on what you want to do.

Just do not go for commercial programming languages or for languages with a little documentation. You will find yourself needing more than just a book to learn a programming language.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, for at least having the curtesy and taking the time to help. Seems like a rare thing around here. I will start with PHP and give it a go and see how I feel.